# How to use the data from parent component to be the useState of child component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component in react js that handles if the user creates a post. I'm also using the data from the parent component to display the detail of the user. Like the username of the user. I'm having problem coz I can't find the way to assign the username coming from the parent of the component to be a part of the useState. The value is there but after the user submit the data the username name is not included.
Can you explain to me or help me why the value is not there?

```
Parent Component    
  const userDetails = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
```

const { userData } = userDetails;

```
  const classes = useStyles();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userDetails) {
      history.push();
    }
  }, [history, userDetails]);

  return (
    <FormContainer>
      <Container component='div' className={classes.homepageContainer}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Container component='div' className={classes.userFeedCard}>
            <Card className={classes.userPostFeedCard}>
              <UserPost userData={userData} />
            </Card>
          </Container>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </FormContainer>
  );
};

Child Component
const UserPost = ({ userInfo }) => {
  
  const [postInfo, setPostInfo] = useState({
    username: userInfo.username,
    description: '',
  });

  const handlePost = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(postInfo);
  };

  return (
    <Container
      component='div'
      className={classes.userPostContainer}
      style={{ padding: '0', margin: '0' }}
    >
      <Card className={classes.userPostCard} style={{ boxShadow: 'none' }}>
        <CardContent style={{ padding: '0 0 1.5em 0' }}>
          <form noValidate onSubmit={handlePost}>
            <Grid container>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <TextField
                  variant='outlined'
                  id='description'
                  name='description'
                  type='text'
                  value={postInfo.description}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  placeholder={`What's on your mind, ${
                    userInfo && userInfo.username
                  }`}
                  fullWidth
                  InputLabelProps={{
                    classes: {
                      root: classes.label,
                      focused: classes.focused,
                    },
                  }}
                  InputProps={{
                    className: classes.textfieldBg,
                    classes: {
                      root: classes.cssOutlinedInputBg,
                      focused: classes.cssFocused,
                      notchedOutline: classes.NonotchedOutline,
                    },
                  }}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid
                xs={12}
                container
                className={classes.postPhotoContainer}
                style={{ padding: '0' }}
              >
                <Grid xs={2} style={{ padding: '0', margin: '0' }}>
                  <Button
                    type='submit'
                    variant='contained'
                    startIcon={<SendIcon />}
                    style={{}}
                  >
                    Upload
                  </Button>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </form>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Comment: You always want a "single source of truth" so you should not duplicate props in state.  Just use the `userInfo` from the props directly.

Comment: What you are doing here sets the *initial value* of the `postInfo` state to include the username from the props.  It will not respond to any changes in the parent component.

Comment: The `userInfo` state in `HomePage` is also an unnecessary duplication of data.  You are already getting that data from Redux.  That's enough!  It should not be stored in state.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @LindaPaiste

Answer (score 1):

#### Single Source of Truth

Every piece of data in your app should have just one one place where it is stored and updated.  You can pass around this data from component to component using `props`.

When you have data in the `state` of multiple components you can wind up with data that is out-of-sync.  The `UserPost` component uses the `userInfo` from props to set the *initial value* of `username` but it will not respond to any changes.

You can simplify your code by removing a lot of unnecessary duplication of data.

`HomePage` accesses the current user from Redux.  It doesn't need any component state.

```
const HomePage = () => {
  const userInfo = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin?.userData);

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    /*...*/
  );
}
```

`UserPost` needs some local state in order to store the `description`.  It gets the `userInfo` from props and should not duplicate the user in its state.  Just access it from props directly.  (Note: you could move the `useSelector` here and get the user from Redux)

`postInfo` is what we would call "derived data".  It is something that you can derive from the props and the state.  You could define this `const` at the top level of the component or inside the `handlePost` callback.  If it is only used by `handlePost` then I would put it there.

```
const UserPost = ({ userInfo }) => {

  // description is a state
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('');

  const handlePost = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // variable derived from props and state
    const postInfo = {
      username: userInfo.username, // from props
      description, // from state
    };

    console.log(postInfo);
  };

  return (
    /* ... */
  );
}
```

In your `TextField`,

```
value={description}
onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this will help me a lot! I made some changes like what you said.